# How can I get the parameters of a function from a function passed as a parameter to my function, in Lua?

Tags: lua, decorator, variadic-functions

I'm trying to decorate multiple functions with a function decorator, and I want to get the parameters of a function that I'm gonna decorate (in this case called `fun` in the parameters) and I want to pass as an argument to the returned function (in this case called `func`) the arguments of the gotten function from the parameters (which is called `fun`)
So it may look like this:

```
local function decorator(fun)
  local function func(fun.args)
    -- Write here custom behaviour to add to the function 'fun'

    fun(fun.args)
  end

  return func
end
```

However, obviously there is no such thing as `fun.args` that was just a way of explaining with more exactitude to you what I want. Take in mind this, I DON'T know the function I want to decorate, and the functions I want to decorate may be different to each other, so this would be a way of ADDING a custom behaviour to a function (as you can see in the code example above)

So, is there a way to do what I'm needing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua supports varargs via `...`. In your case, you'd use it like this:

```
local function decorator(fun)
  local function func(...)
    -- Write here custom behaviour to add to the function 'fun'

    fun(...)
  end

  return func
end
```

And if you want to use the arguments in the "custom behaviour" section, then you can do `local args = {...}`, and then access them numerically (e.g., `args[1]` would contain the first argument).